# Intellij Android test: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I followed this tutorial to achieve unit testing for my android app:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Creating+Unit+Tests

So i made a Android test module and i have the following testclass:
package test.app.com;

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import junit.framework.Assert;

/**
 * This is a simple framework for a test of an Application.  See
 * {@link android.test.ApplicationTestCase ApplicationTestCase} for more information on
 * how to write and extend Application tests.
 * <p/>
 * To run this test, you can type:
 * adb shell am instrument -w \
 * -e class test.app.com.LoginActivityTest \
 * test.app.com.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
 */
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

    public LoginActivityTest() {
        super("test.app.com", LoginActivity.class);
    }

    public void testName() throws Exception {
        LoginActivity activity = getActivity();
        int num = 10;
        int result = activity.test(num);
        Assert.assertEquals(num*2,result);
    }
```

Edit Configuration settings:
Class: test.app.com.LoginActivityTest
method: testname

Project structure:
Dependencies:
MyApp->Provided.

However, if i try to run the test i get the following error:
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

A popup "Empty test suite" appears obove the run button.

The message is: Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly.

Additional info:
I'm using git for version control.

I can't try using the emulator because even after a half hour, it's still loading.

Can you guys help me solve this issue?

I tried uninstalling the app from my device, but that didn't solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, after uninstalling the old apk, you also have to reboot before the old certificate is no longer causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't work either.